# Emoji in Wordpress title tag

Tags: html, wordpress, emoji

how it is possible to add an emoji in the Wordpress-Title-Tag?

In html its like this:

```
<title>&#x1F601</title>
```

But in Worpress, the title would not be encoded into an emoji.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using the actual Unicode character instead of the html encoded version?

Answer (score 2):

Ok sorry the answer is so stupid... i only missed the ';' after the code, so it works with the unicode emojis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WordPress plugin for this. There are multiple options; however, I like hello emoji.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/open-source-emoji/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hello-emoji/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-emoji-one/

You can also check the WordPress.org Codex for a list of 'smileys' or emoticons that are available to WordPress by default:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Smilies

Comment: hm i think this plugin is for comments, right? i want to change the html title tag, which is the Blogtitle by default.

Comment: With Hello Emoji by typing ':' in your editor you'll get an autocomplete list of emoji suggestions. So no - it is not for comments.

Comment: You can try to copy / paste one of these into your Title section?

Comment: Note that you'll have to edit the slug / permalink (otherwise you'll end up with an ugly url)

Comment: Also note that it works in the WordPress text editor, not the visual editor.

Comment: i tried the copy/paste method, but the result was the same. Only the code from the plugin ":+1:" for example was in the title.